# JTextArea and line (word) wrapping

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextarea, word-wrap

I have a JPanel(a) with box layout, and all the components are stacked on it vertically.
Among them, I have a JPanel(b) with horizontal box layout. To that JPanel(b) I have added rigid area, JPanel and JTextArea.

What I want is that JPanel(b) increases its height every time JTextArea expands due to word wrap. However, since my JPanel in beginning has the height of a single row. JTextArea doesn't expand because all space is filled.

Is there a way to fix this, an alternative?

It doesn't have to be JPanel and JTextArea, just something that can contain components and a JTextComponent that suporrts multi line.

```
class Question extends JPanel
{
public JPanel questionArea;
public JTextArea number, question;

public Question(Page page)
{
    setSize(new Dimension(556, 100));
    setBackground(Color.PINK);
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    Border in = BorderFactory.createDashedBorder(Color.BLACK);
    Border out = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 10, 0, Color.WHITE);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(out, in));

    questionArea = new JPanel();
    questionArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(556, 32));
    questionArea.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    questionArea.setLayout(new BoxLayout(questionArea, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    out = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 8, 0, Color.WHITE);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(out, in));

    number = new JTextArea();
    number.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 32));
    number.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    number.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    number.setText("10.");
    number.setEditable(false);

    question = new JTextArea();
    question.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(494, 32));
    question.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    question.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 15));
    question.setText("What is the first question?");

    questionArea.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(35, 32)));
    questionArea.add(number);
    questionArea.add(question);

    add(questionArea);

    page.editArea.add(this, page.content);
}
}
```

break

```
class Page extends JPanel
{
public JPanel editArea;
public Box.Filler blank;

public Page(JPanel panel)
{
    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(92, panel.getPreferredSize().height+40, 794, 1123);

    setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    editArea = new JPanel();
    editArea.setLayout(new BoxLayout(editArea, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    editArea.setBounds(119, 96, 556, 931);
    editArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    blank = new Box.Filler(new Dimension(556, -1), new Dimension(556, 931), new Dimension(556, 931));
    editArea.add(blank);

    add(editArea);

}
}
```

Page class is itself on a JPanel with null layout, no need for code, right?

Comment: Have you set LineWrap & WrapStyleWord to true?

Comment: You don't get it. I have set both, yes, and the text will wrap, but only if there is enough room in the container that contains JTextArea itself (JPanel(b)). However, my container size matches the current size of the JTextArea and I want it to expand when the word wrap occurs. However, it will never occur because the container is too small.

Shortly, I want my JPanel to keep up with the JTextArea auto-resize feature which is blocked because my JPanel is fixed to the JTextArea current height.

Comment: hmm .. looks like _you_ don't get it, so repeating: show an SSCCE that demonstrates what you are doing and how it doesn't live up to your expectations

Comment: use null-layout and suffer ... ;-) Seriously: null layout is a nononeverever in Swing, there's a good probability that it alone already is the reason for the perceived misbehaviour. Didn't check further, though, because the code is a mere snippet instead of a SSCCE (google is your friend if you don't know the abbr)

Comment: and another nononever is to call setXXSize: doing so short-circuits _any_ internal calculation of sizing hints.

Comment: Program is complicated, I can't really extract SSCCE, I would have to paste the whole thing here...

But all that is unneccesarry, I KNOW what the problem is, I'm just looking for alternative...

Comment: you can _always_ create an SSCCE - but shrugs, if you don't want help why ask?

Answer (score 0):

I think horizontal `BoxLayout` is doing you in.

It will display components at their preferred size (using `getPreferredSize()` upon instantiation) and I don't believe it will readily resize it for you. You might want to change Panel(b) to a `BorderLayout`, and add the components to the `EAST`, `WEST`, and the `JTextArea` in `CENTER`.